# How do I compile for 64bit using G++ w/ CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, 64-bit, codeblocks

I'm currently working on creating a shared lib DLL but I need to load it at runtime in a 64 bit environment so it currently doesn't work.

How can I compile 64bit dlls from code blocks using g++ ?

I've tried compiler options like -m64 but none seem to work.

Comment: You should use `-m64` - if that doesn't work, you need to explain in what way "none seem to work".

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks for the reply. I just used -m64 and tried to load the dll. Still says it's 32 bit. Saying that, I'm using 32 bit mingw but when I tried to install the 64 bit I got an error.

Comment: Download https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/ or online installer at https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To compile 64-bit programs on windows using g++, you need [MinGW64](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nv14ecey1bqxuv/MinGW64.zip?dl=0). I believe that Code::Blocks comes with MinGW32.

To install it onto Code::Blocks, extract the zip file to a folder without spaces, such as `C:\MinGW64`

Open Code::Blocks and click on Settings -> Compiler and debugger. Under Selected Compiler, click Copy. In the next box, type something like "MinGW 64-bit Compiler" and click OK.

Then on the Toolchain executables tab, click the Browse button beside each option and browse to the folder you copied MinGW64 to ( `C:\MinGW64` ) and go into the `bin` folder. Set each option as follows:

Compiler's installation directory: The path you specified( `C:\MinGW64` )

C compiler: `gcc.exe`

C++ compiler: `g++.exe` (If you used my link above it will be `g++64.exe`, thanks Super Cat for reminding me)

Linker for dynamic libs: `g++.exe` (`g++64.exe` if you used my link)

Linker for static libs: `ar.exe`

Debugger: There isn't one for MinGW64 yet, clear this and leave it blank

Resource compiler: `windres.exe`

Make program: `make.exe`

Once you have the compiler set up, compile your DLL with the same settings, only using the 64 bit compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. Now I can switch between the 2 compilers easily. Thanks :)

Comment: Just a quick FYI - '`g++.exe`' is actually named '`g++64.exe`'.

Comment: Ah, yes. I created that dropbox link from my setup. I have mine setup so both MinGW64 and MinGW32 are in one folder in the PATH environment so I can just append 32 or 64 to the command to get a 32-bit executable or 64-bit. Thanks Super Cat for reminding me.

Comment: Linker for dynamic libs should also be `g++64.exe` as there is no `g++.exe` executable anywhere in the `MinGW64` folder.

Comment: Added official MinGW-w64 download links in the comment under the question.