# Unable to build using MinGw

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, codeblocks, gnu

I  am trying to build a simple C++ "Hello world" program using MinGW C++.
I downloaded and extracted the program in my c:\ drive as c:\mingw. I then configured code blocks as such. The code that I wrote is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

[image]

When I attempt to build this I get the following errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in TestMinGW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|4|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_sections'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|5|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|13|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_proc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|19|Error: bad register name `%rbp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|20|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_pushreg'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|23|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|24|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_setframe'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|26|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|27|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_stackalloc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|28|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endprologue'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|32|Error: bad register name `%rip)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|33|Error: bad register name `%rip)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|37|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|38|Error: bad register name `%rbp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|44|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endproc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|46|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_proc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|52|Error: bad register name `%rbp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|53|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_pushreg'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|56|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|57|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_setframe'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|59|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|60|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_stackalloc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|61|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endprologue'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|63|Error: bad register name `%rip)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|66|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|67|Error: bad register name `%rbp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|73|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endproc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|75|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_proc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|80|Error: bad register name `%rbp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|81|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_pushreg'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|84|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|85|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_setframe'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|87|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|88|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_stackalloc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|89|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endprologue'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|90|Error: bad register name `%rbp)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|91|Error: bad register name `%rbp)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|93|Error: bad register name `%rbp)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|95|Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `discriminator'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|95|Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `1'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|96|Error: bad register name `%rbp)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|99|Error: bad register name `%rip)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|101|Error: bad register name `%rip)'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|106|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|107|Error: bad register name `%rbp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|113|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endproc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|115|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_proc'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|120|Error: bad register name `%rbp'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|121|Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_pushreg'|
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXBs3ro.s|124|Error: bad register name `%rsp'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: try adding the full mingw folder to your path environment variable

Comment: Do you mean the Windows path environment variable ?

Comment: yes just in case you're missing something

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. I already had c:\mingw\bin in the path

Comment: download a better mingw package: (note that binary names are a bit different bu sure to check exact executables name in the bin folder)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/32-bit/threads-posix/dwarf/

Comment: wonder what the difference is between gcc and gcc-ar ?

Comment: Just downloaded a 64bit from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414511/how-do-i-compile-for-64bit-using-g-w-codeblocks still getting the same result