# Trying to compile .cpp with g++ for 64 bit windows

Tags: c++, windows, g++

First I tried just downloading what you get after searching mingw64 windows. That didn't work. While searching for a solution I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414511/how-do-i-compile-for-64bit-using-g-w-codeblocks), where the answer includes what seems to be a legit version of mingw64.

This being probably the third or fourth mingw64 I've downloaded, I was happy to see a g++64.exe which I assumed would take care of everything. It doesn't, after compiling with `g++64 -o hello.exe -c hello.cpp` and running `hello` I get an error saying `This version of [...]\hello.exe is not compatible[...]`.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried -m64. Is there some additional setting I need to change? Should I post what I get for `g++64 -v`?

Comment: Don't forget to ask almost all warnings by passing  `-Wall` to `g++`

Comment: The easiest way to install `mingw-w64` is to use its installation utility  (as opposed to downloading a binary build).  The installation utility detects the right build for your system.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is wrong, you're not creating a .exe file, but an object file that you need to link to produce an executable. Do it like this:

```
g++64 -o hello.exe hello.cpp
```

The -c argument tells the compiler to just compile but not link your code. You can do the above in 2 steps, compile and link:

```
g++64 -c -o hello.o  hello.cpp
g++64 -o hello.exe hello.o
```

Comment: Without using -c I get an error `undefined reference to 'WinMain'`. Do I need to pass some libraries or something (additional flags)?

Comment: @Nimitz14 make sure your program contains `int main() { ` ... `}`