# Intel DRNG giving only giving 4 bytes of data instead of 8

Tags: c++, random, intel

I am trying to implement [Intel DRNG](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/4d/91/DRNG_Software_Implementation_Guide_2.0.pdf) in c++.

According to its guide to generate a 64 bit unsigned long long the code should be:

```
int rdrand64_step (unsigned long long *rand)
{
    unsigned char ok;
    asm volatile ("rdrand %0; setc %1"
                  : "=r" (*rand), "=qm" (ok));
    return (int) ok;
}
```

However the output of this function `rand` is only giving me an output of only 32 bits as shown.

```
        bd4a749d
        d461c2a8
        8f666eee
        d1d5bcc4
        c6f4a412
```

any reason why this is happening?

more info: the IDE I'm using is codeblocks

Comment: On which operating system and which version of C++ and which compiler ? C++11 has [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), better use it (since it is portable). [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is *not* a compiler (it runs one, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) but an IDE

Comment: ***the compiler I'm using is codeblocks*** Code::Blocks is an IDE. I assume the compiler is some version of mingw.

Comment: Linux has `/dev/random` see [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html), and [mingw](http://mingw.org/) is -or contains- a port of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Run `g++ -v` or `g++ --version` in a terminal. A recent enough mingw should provide a C++11 compiler

Comment: I believe this will not work in 32 bit code. Although I may be reading the documentation wrong.

Comment: But *why* do you need to *implement* some DRNG? Why can't you *use* `<random>` ?? Please edit your question to explain!

Comment: @basile it's a simple how to implement DRNG in which I do need to use DRNG and I'm on a windows platform so I can use /dev/random. I would appreciate if u can help rather then trying to rant on my post.

Comment: @drescherjm how do u know its a 32 bit code?

Comment: The mingw that is bundled with Code::Blocks is likely 32 bit.

Comment: @drescherjm is there any 64 bit complier that I can use?

Comment: There are several 64 bit compilers that will work with Code::Blocks.

Comment: My point in that RNG is a very delicate subject. I would recommend trusting an existing implementation

Comment: Is it wise to tweak the code in this way? 1) left shit 32 bits 2) run the DRNG again for the lower bits.  The only problem is if I do that do I still maintain the entropy of the random number generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`int _rdrand64_step (unsigned __int64* val)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=rdrand&expand=5450,4247) from `immintrin.h` instead of writing inline asm.  You don't need it, and there are many reasons (including this one) to avoid it: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

---

In this case, **the problem is that you're probably compiling 32-bit code**, so of course 64-bit `rdrand` is not encodeable.  But the way you used inline-asm ended up giving you a 32-bit `rdrand`, and storing garbage from another register for the high half.

`gcc -Wall -O3 -m32 -march=ivybridge` (and similar for clang) produces ([on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSBnVAV2OUxAHI8A7AgamLpiAQx7oAbABYA%2BgwKYADvwjMeDPMB6Z0/ADaoewfYeMAqUeICUAUgAMAQRsB2AEL2H/L/zUatO/mQEEWJ%2BVABrGwBmd0dvfhEGAFt%2BADdUPRECPD1MFRsAJgKhS11CgFY7aNd%2BBkwCZH4K2kKCj3iOzu8QJqLogBFiVpULMXQrUl62qP6ARyThiAirWxj272J61h4VXgIrMMi1xxd%2Bjw9fTW1dAyMTO%2BY6mUSkiHS8caa3da9L/xvTPdjKVqj9%2BAB3BA5TAQMBgEpjaRyBSKCCFCSlFaguIbLbEHYg45OZxnE4nApRPAAMywVP4MhkAA8ABwSGRImTnCm8ZB6ZhYJpRADCeCSST2xF4ADoENFsB4APRmDx7QIiPR6GQS3gaZCqdRXAK3YzG/ijaxfWKeXEEbb0hHiJHyJQQTHY4mkhxmBUXA3/IEBx6YLV8SUGvXvT4uK3xP7XAOmwkx7yQ6GwsAyB2SWTO1HozGrZNeTa2/GCMbu05cqKYcTUjycCZ6LjlTikHhcOxt1BcIWFdwFGpMVjsXpRWhtgidxsTcIgcdS5lSWi0Owr2jOKTOOzb5ykZucKRtjucLukHucNsMEB2UhT0%2BN0hwWAwRAoVBJRTQsgUCBoT/fiAwDOAUpBUjkCjENeEAAEbTqQMG8CEACeXATqQ/5JLWBAAPI8HoqEPqQWBJGIwC5PB%2BCbMg2SpJg15EZgjKYMgzAKGhbZ7JgB5ngQkpJBxTZ4DB16QBMqCKNkhgMQAtAA6uqej8DJOFRMppFsLKMx4KkyEwZK6DAHkMlJFEBRXiwbAcLQTYtse8EXiyEgydI/DAMgjTOFKBQqLghAkGO9D8EKH5frkoSFOOViTtOKykHOZmLnYBTlM45TlAAnBItASHYrJSPuXBHqQAmVO2DlcFeN53rFT6vhASAsAQihseQlD/mFmDEHQpA6P53U2YVnCtuVREXpFtAQoQCD8E5LlSG5Hn8F55k1Q%2BcUIJgIhYN1EC2YebalbeJ5nheVW3veXZxQlUiLil5QSOlUgZbQGWZXuB5RPZY2VWtV11fAz5vh135tX%2BoWAbyZGVLe4F6JB0FwURiE8ChHEYR%2BWF8HhBGUZgpFGBRRFUSxtH0fBTEsWxHCcOhXE8ZO/GCfuwmiXt56SXg0lcPJinKap6khEEAw6XpBlGepZkWSO1n7SNJ3dlwc2uVDdzlFKdga75%2BBEBFFJBSFAHhWOUTRX9M7xfOURSlEtt2/b9tDcVR2jadv3XhdtVAw1IBNS1BBgyD4Xzr1OskHQcvfW7nCRWp4LTbNrLzYEmRqxrGsxetEybdtXWUPtzsgGVCvnu71WXRbCXWw7Nd20NX2u4rl7m3FB6rSXZ0txMdFQVzHZSEAA%3D%3D%3D)):

```
In function 'rdrand64_step':
7 : <source>:7:1: warning: unsupported size for integer register

rdrand64_step:
    push    ebx
    rdrand ecx; setc al
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+8]    # load the pointer arg
    movzx   eax, al
    mov     DWORD PTR [edx], ecx
    mov     DWORD PTR [edx+4], ebx    # store garbage in the high half of *rand
    pop     ebx
    ret
```

I guess you called this function with a caller that happened to have `ebx=0`.  Or else you used a different compiler that did something different.  Maybe something else happens after inlining.  If you looked at disassembly of what you actually compiled, you could explain exactly what's going on.

---

**If you'd used the intrinsic**, you would have gotten `error: '_rdrand64_step' was not declared in this scope`, because `immintrin.h` only declares it in 64-bit mode (and with a `-march` setting that implies rdrand support.  Or `[-mrdrnd`][3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372893/rdrand-and-rdseed-intrinsics-gcc-and-intel-c).  Best option: **use `-march=native`** if you're building on the target machine).

You'd also get significantly more efficient code for a retry loop, at least with clang:

```
unsigned long long use_intrinsic(void) {
    unsigned long long rand;
    while(!_rdrand64_step(&rand));  // TODO: retry limit in case RNG is broken.
    return rand;
}

use_intrinsic:                          # @use_intrinsic
.LBB2_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    rdrand  rax
    jae     .LBB2_1
    ret
```

That avoids setcc and then testing that, which is of course redundant.  gcc6 has syntax for returning flag results from inline asm.  You can also use `asm goto` and put a jcc inside the asm, jumping to a `label: return 1;` target or falling through to a `return 0`.  (The inline-asm docs have an example of doing this.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  See also [the inline-assembly tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info).)

Using your inline-asm, clang (in 64-bit mode) compiles it to:

```
use_asm:
.LBB1_1:
    rdrand  rax
    setb    byte ptr [rsp - 1]
    cmp     byte ptr [rsp - 1], 0
    je      .LBB1_1
    ret
```

(clang makes bad decisions for constraints with multiple options that include memory.)

gcc7.2 and ICC17 actually end up with better code from the asm than from the intrinsic.  They use `cmovc` to get a 0 or 1 and then `test` that.  It's pretty dumb.  But that's a gcc/ICC missed optimization that will hopefully be.

Comment: yea it appears i am using a 32-bit compiler i tried to change that using [minGW64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414511/how-do-i-compile-for-64bit-using-g-w-codeblocks) but when i test run it using `cout << “sizeof(void*) = ” << sizeof(void*) << ";" << endl;` i get 4 instead of the expected [8](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/64Bit_Windows) and using my code i still only get a 32 bit return. its it because my IDE is 32 bit?

Comment: @albusSimba: your IDE has to pass `-m64` if its default is `-m32`.  IDK anything about your IDE, but there's no reason a 32-bit process would have trouble running a 64-bit executable.  It doesn't load the compiler as a library (does it?)

Comment: Yea i have alr pass `-m64` but it still doesn't pass the simple test of `cout << “sizeof(void*) = ” << sizeof(void*) << ";" << endl;` which means it is still running on 32 bits

Comment: @albusSimba: Also pass `-v` (verbose) to see if it's appending a `-m32` after user-supplied options.  You could also check if `__x86_64__` is defined by the preprocessor, in case it's doing something weird like 32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode (like the [Linux x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI)).  Or just google more about using your IDE.

Comment: `inlining failed in call to always_inline 'int _rdrand64_step(long long unsigned int*)` i swap to clion and my code seem to have worked but i was wondering why using `immintrin.h` throws me back this error it's the 1st time i've seen this error.

Comment: @albusSimba: that happens when you use an intrinsic for an instruction the target doesn't support.  That's why I used `-march=ivybridge` in my answer.  Use `-march=native`.

Comment: where do i input `-march=native`? in the cmake file? do u have an example?

Comment: @albusSimba: On the compiler command line, however you do that in your build system.  For an example, click the godbolt link, where `-march=ivybridge` is in the compiler command-line options box, along with `-O3 -Wall`.